# Firebase security rule for data in same child

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

My database structure is.

```
Homeland
 +Ui4PSHU0kCPGpFJ6jWIJPOdLvEds
  +service
  +quta
  +period
+55dwaSHU0kCPGpFJ6jWIJPOdLvEds
  +service
  +quta
  +period
```

I want to make public "service" and "quta" childs, but only registered user can shown the "period" child.But there is an issue about able to my user directory.

First I want to test for able to my $uid.But I can't.It's work when I remove to $uid only use "Homeland".So it's didn't work

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Homeland": {
         "$uid" : {
           ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth !== null"
         },
        },
    ".read": "auth !== null",
    ".write": "auth !== null"
  }
}
```

This is work

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Homeland": {
           ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth !== null"
        },
    ".read": "auth !== null",
    ".write": "auth !== null"
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Change my security rules as samthecodingman mentioned.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Homeland": {
      "$uid" : {
        "service": {
          ".read": true, // <-- publically readable
          ".write": "auth.uid === $uid" // <-- writable only by owner
        },
        "quta": {
          ".read": true, // <-- publically readable
          ".write": "auth.uid === $uid" // <-- writable only by owner
        },
        "period": {
          ".read": "auth !== null", // <-- readable by any logged in user
          ".write": "auth.uid === $uid" // <-- writable only by owner
        }
      },
    },
    "$other": { // <-- everywhere else not named above
      ".read": "auth !== null", // <-- allows read if logged in
      ".write": "auth !== null" // <-- allows write if logged in
    }
  }
}
```

Code

```
var kullanici = firebase.database().ref().child("Homeland").child(uservaluefrominput).child("service");
kullanici.on('value' ,function(datasnapshot) {


     sifre = datasnapshot.val();

     console.log(sifre);



});
```

But code and simulation both are denied the read value.

Catch the error.Note: This time I declared the user id clear.

```
try {

kullanici = firebase.database().ref().child("Homeland").child("Ui4PSHU0kCPGpFJ6jWIJPOdLvEO2").child("service");
kullanici.on('value' ,function(datasnapshot) {


     sifre = datasnapshot.val();

     console.log(sifre);



});

} catch (someError) {
  console.log('got some error: ', someError);
}
```

Comment: Please add the code that triggers the problem to your questions. Without code rules are pretty meaningless.

Comment: What is the error when you add the line `kullanici.on('value', (s)=>console.log(s), (err) => console.error(err))` below `var kullanici = ...`?

Comment: I didn't sure how I use your code and I use the try-catch method, but I get nothing on console check my code on the first message, please.

Comment: try and catch won't work in the way you expect for asynchronous code. The line I included in the above comment is a debugging function. Insert it as-is on the line beneath `kullanici = firebase.database().ref()...` and then run your code. All it does is take the response from `on('value', ...)` and convert it to a logged message in the console. Then copy whatever the error is here

Comment: "kullanici.on('value', (s)=>console.log(s), (err) => console.error(err)) ,function(datasnapshot) { " this line gives me a SyntaxError: unexpected token: ')'

Answer (score 1):

It is important to note that [database rules cascade](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security#section-authorization). Even if you denied access to `/users/$uid` to anyone other than `$uid` but allowed access to `/users/` to anyone, anyone would be able to modify the deeper location `/users/$uid`.

In your rules above, even though you have configured rules for `/Homeland/$uid`, you have allowed read/write access to the root database for any logged in user.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Homeland": {
      "$uid" : {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "auth !== null"
      },
    },
    ".read": "auth !== null", // <-- allows read everywhere if logged in
    ".write": "auth !== null" // <-- allows write everywhere if logged in
  }
}
```

To fix this, you can introduce the `$others` key so that a logged in user can read/write anywhere in your database except underneath `/Homeland` unless otherwise allowed.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Homeland": {
      "$uid" : {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "auth !== null"
      },
    },
    "$other": { // <-- everywhere else not named above
      ".read": "auth !== null", // <-- allows read if logged in
      ".write": "auth !== null" // <-- allows write if logged in
    }
  }
}
```

The next step is to restrict access to `/service`, `/quta` and `/period` under the `/Homeland/$uid` key.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Homeland": {
      "$uid" : {
        "service": {
          ".read": true, // <-- publically readable
          ".write": "auth.uid === $uid" // <-- writable only by owner
        },
        "quta": {
          ".read": true, // <-- publically readable
          ".write": "auth.uid === $uid" // <-- writable only by owner
        },
        "period": {
          ".read": "auth !== null", // <-- readable by any logged in user
          ".write": "auth.uid === $uid" // <-- writable only by owner
        }
      },
    },
    "$other": { // <-- everywhere else not named above
      ".read": "auth !== null", // <-- allows read if logged in
      ".write": "auth !== null" // <-- allows write if logged in
    }
  }
}
```

However, because of the mixed permissions levels under `/Homeland`, you are limited by what queries you can perform on this data. As an example, you can't just list off all the users under `/Homeland` using a query because the read operation will be denied.

A query that wouldn't work would be:

```
firebase.database().ref('/Homeland').on('child_added', (snap) => { ... })`
```

To fix this in as simple a way as possible, you can split `/Homeland` into `/HomelandPublic` and `/HomelandRegistered` based on who can access the data. The rules for this would be similar to:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "HomelandPublic": {
      "$uid" : {
        ".write": "auth.uid === $uid" // <-- writable only by owner
      },
      ".read": true // <-- publically readable
    },
    "HomelandRegistered": {
      "$uid" : {
        ".write": "auth.uid === $uid" // <-- writable only by owner
      },
      ".read": "auth !== null" // <-- readable by any logged in user
    },
    "$other": { // <-- everywhere else not named above
      ".read": "auth !== null", // <-- allows read if logged in
      ".write": "auth !== null" // <-- allows write if logged in
    }
  }
}
```

The query from before would now be changed to:

```js
// get publicly accessible data
firebase.database().ref('/HomelandPublic').on('child_added', (snap) => { ... }) // alternatively: once('value', (snap) => {})

// get data accessible by registered users
if (firebase.auth().currentUser) {
  firebase.database().ref('/HomelandRegistered').on('child_added', (snap) => { ... }) // alternatively: once('value', (snap) => {})
}
```

This should give you enough knowledge to adapt it to your situation and needs.

Comment: I can't split or duplicate my homeland directory.Because all my user data inside this directory.And it will work very heavy If I split the homeland directory to /register and /public.However,It's didn't work" $other".Updated my first message how I used.